# Ajustar tamaño para imagen dentro de boton android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Como puedo ajustar el ancho y alto de la imagen del siguiente botón

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
android:text="Button"/>
```

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es controlar el tamaño del botón. o si no te sirve podrías cambiar el tamaño del botón y darle un color transparente para que no se vea raro.

Comment: No se puede, para lograrlo tienes que tener imágenes de diferentes tamaños y/o ajustar el Padding en tu Button, espero te ayude esta respuesta, pero si necesitas un ejemplo de código contestame y con gusto te ayudo. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No se puede, pero se puede solventar con un linear layout y trabajarlo como si fuera un botón.

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/information" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cualquiera de estas instrucciones me sirvieron fitXY o centerInside, centerInside ajusto mejor la imagen a imgbutton y adjustViewBounds para hacer que ajusten sus límites debido a la escala aun que no note cambio al usar esta instrucción en el diseño.

<ImageButton

android:scaleType="fitXY"

android:scaleType="centerInside"

android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>